# Detect an Image using apache Tika in any document?

Tags: apache-tika

I am using **Apache Tika** for extracting the content of uploaded files and I do not want to parse files which are having embedded image/s. As of now, I am using ToXMLContentHandler and try to find `<img>` tag.

```
    val parser   = new AutoDetectParser()
    val handler  = new ToXMLContentHandler()
    val metaData = new Metadata
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metaData, getParseContext)

    val xmlFileContent = XML.loadString(handler.toString)
    val isDocHasImg    = (xmlFileContent \\ "body" \\ "img").toList.nonEmpty
```

Is there any better solution to achieve this? I am using Scala.

Comment: Best would probably be to ask Apache Tika for all the embedded resources, rather than the text, and check for images in that

Comment: What would be the API to get image resources ?

Comment: But I don't want to continue the execution if the document contains embedded image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for solution, you can make use of **EmbeddedDocumentExtractor** class.

```
class EmbeddedImageFinder() extends EmbeddedDocumentExtractor {
  override def shouldParseEmbedded(metadata: Metadata): Boolean = {
    if(metadata.get("Content-Type").contains("image/")) {
       isImageExists = true
    }
    false
  }

  override def parseEmbedded(stream: InputStream, handler: ContentHandler,
                             metadata: Metadata, outputHtml: Boolean): Unit = {}
}
```

then add this to the ParserContext

```
context.set(classOf[EmbeddedDocumentExtractor], new EmbeddedImageFinder)
```